# "they can really drew you in"

Tags: grammaticality

> So on the pro side, they're very visible, they're very attractive, they're eye-catching, and they can really drew you in as a potential buyer and prospect.

What I mean by that is the meaning of "they can really drew you in."

And a grammar question: after *can* it used a past tense verb, *drew*. Why?

Comment: "they can really drew you in " is, as you have guessed, not grammatical.

Comment: It's probably just a spelling mistake.  "Draw" would be correct there.

Comment: You will need to present your reasons for believing that this is not a mere typo. If you don't have a reason to believe that, then by extension this question has no reason to exist. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**to draw in**  [MacMillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/draw-in) a phrasal verb

As in the grammatically correct:

*...  and they can really draw you in as a potential buyer and prospect.*

> in a conversation or situation, often when they do not want to be
>   involved

I know of no grammatically correct use of 'drew' that can be used in your stated question or for the sense of this phrasal verb.